# Set image for each node in D3js

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

Good morning, we are working on a social network visualizer and we're using nodes, de created a graph.json for import data ( with name , picture and group) on the graph and we want to set an image for each user on the graph but it doesn't work

Example of what we did in

```
graph.json

{
  "nodes": [
    {
      "name": "Myriel",
      "group": 1,
      "picture": "https://web-link/images.png"
    },
    {
      "name": "sam",
      "group": 1,
      "picture": "https://web-link/image-zzz.png"
    },
```

What we did in

index.html

```
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 960,
    height = 500

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .gravity(0.05)
    .distance(100)
    .charge(-100)
    .size([width, height]);

d3.json("graph.json", function(error, json) {
  if (error) throw error;

  force
      .nodes(json.nodes)
      .links(json.links)
      .start();

  var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
      .data(json.links)
    .enter().append("line")
      .attr("class", "link");

  var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(json.nodes)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .call(force.drag);

  nodes.append("image")
       .attr("xlink:href",function (d) {
            return "../image/"+d.entityType+".jpg";")
      .attr("x", -8)
      .attr("y", -8)
      .attr("width", 16)
      .attr("height", 16);
```

Comment: Where does this `entityType` come from? Shouldn't you set the picture url for `xlink:href`? `attr("xlink:href", d => d.picture)`

Comment: Oh i even didn't notice it , am beginner, i putted the picture and the issue has been SOLVED Thank you very Much.

Comment: The Other issue i get is that i want to put only one person on the graph as soon as i delete nodes in the graph.json then the graph stop working